# Child_process is not running python inside of vscode extension (extension.js)

Tags: node.js, python-3.x, vscode-extensions, child-process

I am using the following code to run a python from node. The code works fine as a separate file but when I put it in a VSCode Extension (extension.js), it says graph.py not found.

```
const {spawn} = require('child_process')

const child = spawn('python3', ['graph.py'])

child.stdout.on('data', (data)=>{
    console.log(`stdout: ${data}`)
})

child.stderr.on('data', (data)=>{
    console.log(`stderr: ${data}`)
})

child.on('error', (error)=> console.log(`error: ${error.message}`))

child.on('exit', (code, signal)=>{
    if(code) console.log(`Process exit with code: ${code}`)
    if(signal) console.log(`Process killed with signal: ${signal}`)
    console.log(`DONE!!`)
})
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?
TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this line at the top of your code:

```
console.log(__dirname);
```

It will show you from what directory your extension code is being launched from. The `graph.py` file is probably not present in this directory.

You can either include the full path to the `graph.py` in the spawn function like this:

```
const child = spawn('python3', ["C:/Path/To/Your/File/graph.py"])
```

Or add the `graph.py` file in the directory your extension is being launched from.

**For a permanent and deliverable solution you have to find a way to bundle python sub processes in a JS VSCode extension**. This is not as easy as it may sound especially if you plan to publish your extension in the marketplace but **a guide is available** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76650864/11184186). Instead you may find useful this [python packet](https://github.com/CodeWithSwastik/vscode-ext) which enables you to code, build and publish (using vsce) extensions made with python.